# Sublime Autocomplete for Web Development

Tags: autocomplete, sublimetext3

As the title shown, does anyone recommend autocomplete add-on for Sublime?
Or any recommended way to speed up the coding process of autocompleting the tags for web development in Sublime?

Comment: I just find out go to Sublime > Tools > Command palette > search "install package",
then I can have many plug-ins!

Type the keyword "Auto" to get the ones.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try [Auto Close](https://github.com/sh4nks/sublime-text-plugin-autoclose).

This will fullfill your requirement.

If you don't know how to install package. You can follow following steps.

1. First open package manager ctrl+shift+p
2. Search and select Add Repository. Then paste the github link.
3. After that again open package manager. Search and select Install
   Package.
4. Search and select Auto Close

Then your are good to go.